# Getting the borders coordinates of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have this xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/background"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like to draw somthing on the LinearLayout `surface` borders in a class

i have already took control of the layout in a class:

```
        LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
    surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
```

so how do i get the coordinates of the borders of the layout?
Tnx for the help :D

Comment: border you mean left,right,top, bottom ?

Comment: yea, the most left,right, top and bottom of the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use  [MarginParam](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) to get margin borders in pixel

```
View view = findViewById(R.layout.main) //or however you need it
LayoutParams l = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

l.leftMargin;
l.rightMargin;
l.topMargin;
l.bottomMargin;
```

or use [getLocationOnScreen(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen

Comment: how do i use the getLocationOnScreen(view)?